# Unable to Install AWX with minikube on Centos 8

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ansible-awx

I am trying to install **awx** v19.0 on **CentOS** 8. Installing **Minikube**, AWX-Operator, AWX itself and enabling ingress addon works without any problems and all pods are running.

But i can't access the **awx** dashboard with browser. I can find minikube logs errors like:

```
kubelet[168646]: I0120 14:37:15.885758  168646 docker_sandbox.go:401] "Failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker" err="Couldn't find network status for ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-j27jf through plugin: invalid network status for"
```

Unfortunately i am not an expert in docker and kubernetes and would be happy for any help.

**Minikube Version** v1.24.0

**Kubectl Version** v1.22.3

**Docker Version** 20.10.12

**Installation Steps:**

1. Disabling SELINUX, Installed docker, minikube, conntrack-tools, kubeadm, kubectl
2. minikube start --driver=none
3. minikube addons enable ingress
4. git clone https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator.git
5. cd awx-operator & git checkout 0.15.0
6. export NAMESPACE=default & make deploy
7. kubectl apply -f awx-instance.yml